# SDL surfaces and BMPs

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, bmp, surface

I have been attempting to work with SDL and openGL for a project Im working on, and to enable easy testing, I would like to be able to draw in 2D to the screen and the only way I have found to allow me to do this is SDL surfaces to create and draw BMP images.  This is fine as being able to save the image will be a nice feature later on but if there is another better way to do this with openGL or some other method, please say :).

This is the code I am currently using:

```
int w = 255;
int h = 255;
SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,w,h,32,0,0,0,0);
SDL_LockSurface(surface);
int bpp = surface->format->BitsPerPixel;
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
    {
        Uint32 *p = (Uint32 *)surface->pixels + (i * surface->pitch) + (j * bpp);
        *p = SDL_MapRGB(surface->format,i,j,i);
    }
}
SDL_UnlockSurface(surface);
SDL_SaveBMP(surface, "Test.bmp");
```

This is just a basic test thing to allow me to get to terms with how to do this, Im sure I have some issues with memory handling here but Im not sure when if at all to delete *p.  The issue that I am having the biggest problem with though is where I use SDL_MapRGB.  the program crashes when it hits this with a SIGSEGV segmentation fault and I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not free the memory pointed by `p`.

But after use, you have to free the `surface` as

```
SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
```

Also, `bpp` is in bits. You have to divide it by `8` to get it in bytes.

And, to do arithmetic in bytes, you have to use

```
Uint32 *p = (Uint32 *)((Uint8 *)surface->pixels + (i * surface->pitch) + (j * bpp));
```

Comment: so I changed the bpp line to int bpp = surface->format->BitsPerPixel / 8, and the byte arithmetic line to what you said but I get a new error: cannot convert 'Uint8* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'Uint32* {aka unsigned int*}' in initialzation.  Im only using Uint32 because from what I read, that allows me to use up to 255 for each of the R, G and B values so I assume its what I need.

Comment: never mind, I used `Uint32 *p = (Uint32 *)((Uint8 *)surface->pixels + (i * surface->pitch) + (j * bpp))` on a whim and it worked, I just needed to convert to Uint32, thanks!!

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the pointer cast issue. I have updated my answer.